# Should I leave or remove sand under a demolished brick walkway to allow grass to grow?

Tags: grass, lawn-repair

I started demolishing an old brick walkway in my backyard and I found sand underneath about a good 3 inches worth of sand. My question is: If I leave the sand underneath and add about 2 inches of topsoil over the sand, will my grass grow on this top soil sitting on top of sand? Is it a bad idea to leave the sand down there? Should I remove it?

Comment: Most good installs of brick pavers start with a layer of sand, if you put topsoil on top it will be fine and even better if you can mix the 2 in my opinion. Grass grows in sand dunes but will do better with some good soil mixed in

Answer (score 6):

Just put the topsoil over the sand and seed it. The earthworms, and other dirt fauna will eventually mix it together.

It wouldn't hurt to mix it yourself perhaps with a hoe, but it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend removal - a little bit mixed in with soil is fine, but 2 inches of topsoil over 3 inches of sand means, although your grass will grow okay, if its a high traffic area, it won't be 'stable', meaning it'll slip and slide about a bit, so won't remain level and even. If, though, it's not a high traffic area and the only walking across it will be you with a mower occasionally, it'll probably be okay. As its an old path, the risk of salts in the sand will be minimal.